# limit editor window height of ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, height

I can't find a way to limit the height of the ckeditor window.
I've tried all the solutions I've found through google and none work: Tables, divs, config commands after the CKEDITOR call like this is supposed to work but doesn't:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>CKEDITOR.replace('cTitle1');CKEDITOR.config.height = '800px';</script>
```

I have the latest version of ckeditor.
I don't want to limit it globally, just specific instances because there are times I want it to be regular size, and times I need it to be less tall.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass configuration object directly to replace method:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    height: '400px'
} );
```

If you want to prevent the editor from resizing, you can also set [`config.resize_enabled`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-resize_enabled) to `false` in the configuration object:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    height: '400px',
    resize_enabled: false
} );
```

Please take a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/szymonkups/fgpc2Lr8/).

If you only want to limit height when the editor is being resized, you can add [`config.resize_maxHeight`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-resize_maxHeight) to the configuration object. Check the "Editor Resizing Customization" [sample](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/resize.html) and [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_resize) for more options and examples.